# Not able to access wildcard subdomain in Django app on online server

Tags: python-3.x, django, apache, cpanel

I am hosting a Django app on managed server with passenger_wsgi file. Let assume app main url is 'www.mysite.com'. When i visit this it shows me the homepage. What i want is to use wildcard subdomains in the app.
Like [www.user1.mysite.com](http://www.user1.mysite.com) , [www.user2.mysite.com](http://www.user2.mysite.com) , [www.user3.mysite.com](http://www.user3.mysite.com) and so on, it can be any wildcard.

I have created a wildcard subdomain from cpanel like "*.mysite.com" , also added wildcard in my django settings.py file too. But when i visit the  "www.user1.mysite.com" browser says

> Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

settings.py

```
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.mysite.com','mysite.com']
```

Any kind of help would be great.

Thanks..!!

Comment: Could you share the settings.py ?

Comment: @Mythilydevaraj i have updated the question, added settings.py.

Comment: ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'], Try if it works

Comment: I have tried it before, but it didn't work.